# Error when trying to update API in API Manager

Tags: wso2

I started with a fresh install of the API Manager.  I can create an API just fine but I can not update it.

I am logged in as a 'creator'role as defined in the documentation of what roles to create.  The same user is logged in that is trying to modify it.  Even if i just create a new API then immediately try to update with ( with out any changes ) I get the following error.

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-30 13:16:41,059] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error while updating the API- ItemService-1.0 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while updating the API :ItemService
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:666)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:496)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag:6)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_9(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:35)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:116)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:666)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:579)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:425)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to reset the WSDL : /registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/creator--ItemService1.0.wsdl
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:787)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:541)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException:  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:767)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at '/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/creator--ItemService1.0.wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/creator--ItemService1.0.wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2259)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:84)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/creator--ItemService1.0.wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:173)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2238)
    ... 69 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with WSO2 APIM 1.6.0.
I get around it by redefining the WSDL to the previous value.
For example when using the sample CDYNE API sample you originally used a WSDL path of:

http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?WSDL

But when you later attempt to update that path is now:

/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--NoAuthTNVerify1.0.0.wsdl

I upated that line back to:

http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?WSDL

and was then able to save my edits.

Now...WHY does the path change?   or WHY doesn't WSO2 APIM deploy the wsdl to that location?  That I don't konw, maybe someone from WSO2 could explain.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar results running APIM 1.5.0 and trying to update an API through the API Publisher application. In fact, I cannot even save the API at all.

I initially created the API through the Publisher API endpoint as described in the docs:

https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-AddUpdateAPI

All seemed to work, as I got this response:

{"error" : false}

When I try to save the API in the Publisher web app, I see this error:
"Error while updating the API- testAPI-v1"

In the logs I see the following:

```
ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error while updating the API- testAPI-v1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:425)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:716)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag:6)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5.call(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_9(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:35)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:111)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

According to this Jira ticket, this bug was discovered in v1.3:

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1024

It does appear to have been fixed.